# how to split string with English and Chinese into two halves using regular expression in R?

Tags: regex, r

I have a string like the one below:

```
地址123 Address123
```

It is actually a bilingual address which I need to split them into Chinese and English.

The program is not word `Address` does not always behind a bunch of numbers, it may be numbers, or sometimes another Chinese character. But you can assume that a space is in front of `Address`.

To make the things more complicated, English character can also be found in the Chinese address.

Can I split it using regular expression in R?

Comment: If you cannot describe a logical rule that will reliably split these strings, then I guess you can't.

Comment: In that particular string separating them by " " would do the job. Could you add more examples that illustrate all cases of how the address can look like?

Answer (score 0):

English=str_extract(x,"[A-Z]+([A-z]+)*")

Data<-data.frame(Data,English)

Comment: When answering, it would be better to include some explanation and not only code.